# Running a Java application (JAR file) in a panel of another Java application

Tags: java, swing, jar

Is there a way of running a Java application (`a.jar`) in a GUI of another Java application (GUI of `b.jar`)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a specific example of the more general question:

> Can I access and use an object from one Jar file in another Jar file.

Yes this is possible and in fact is done all the time, but the applications must be set up to allow this, i.e.,

- If the JPanel of interest is obtainable in a public way, either through a public variable (bad) or a public getter method or constructor.
- Then the jar file of interest needs to be in the class path of the class that needs it. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans, then the IDE must be configured so that the jar file is in the *build* path.
- And you'll need to import the appropriate classes with their full package name, call appropriate constructors and methods, etc...
- As with most coding questions, the devil's almost always in the details, so if you're still stuck, please give us some more information and code, and we'll see if we can give you more specific answers.